# How to display foreign key on Django 1.11 admin page?

Tags: django, python-2.7

I’m upgrading from Django 1.9 to 1.11 and getting "Error during template rendering" on admin portal.  
It happens only on change or add page and not when listing. It also only happens when model has a reference field.  
Here is my model (simplified a bit). User is a foreign key. If I exclude it with:  exclude = ['user'], then the page displayed correctly (except displaying the user). What do i miss?

```
class Task(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(
    primary_key=True, editable=False)
    task_code = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    level = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=10)
    user = models.ForeignKey('account.User', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


@admin.register(Task, site=admin_site)
class TaskAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('task_code', 'user', 'start', 'end', 'level')
    list_filter = ('level', 'task_code')
    search_fields = ('id',)

    def start(self, obj):
        return obj.timespan.lower

    def end(self, obj):
        return obj.timespan.upper
```

On admin page list entries looks OK, but when i proceed to change or add an entry i get this:

[image: the error]

Comment: Adding these foreign key fields to the admin's readonly_fields also make the detailed page to appear without errors. This obviously doesn't resolve my issue, as these fields supposed to remain editable